# CSS Textbox alignment inside div together with the an image

Tags: html, css, textbox

I'm trying to align a `textbox` inside a `<div>` - using the class `.textbox`

CSS Code

```
.sec1 {
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   display: relative;
}

.textbox {
   display: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.subcars {
   display: inline-flex;
}

.selectcar {
   width: 80%;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="subcars">
    <div class="sec1">
         <button class="bot"><img class="selectcar" src="Images/caradd2.png" alt="selectcar"></button>
         <br><input name="cars1" class="textbox"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

The results so far is (I'm using pesticide to clarify the elements):

[image]

As it is possible to see, the text box is not centered inside the `<div>`, how can I fix it?

Comment: Never heard of `display: relative` and `display: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

As @m4n0 mentioned in the comments, relative and absolute are not invalid values for display attribute. So, you don't need them in your code.

And to center the textbox, you can add `margin-left` property with a value accordingly under `.textbox` css.